# How do diff over ssh?

Tags: ssh, diff

How do I diff files/folders across machines provided that the only connectivity available is ssh?

Comment: There's a relatively similar question at [#16661: How can I diff two RedHat Linux servers?](http://serverfault.com/questions/16661/how-can-i-diff-two-redhat-linux-servers). The answer there, to save the clicks, is `rsync -ani --delete / root@remotehost:/` but [the full answer](http://serverfault.com/a/16665/86325) gives more detail.

Comment: Quite many answers here, but which approach is the faster?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Finally I've found great solution: vimdiff

```
vimdiff /path/to/file scp://remotehost//path/to/file
```

thanks to http://linux.spiney.org/remote_diff_with_vim_and_ssh
see also http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075 .

Comment: What about directories? :)

Comment: Here is an example: vimdiff .bash_profile scp://vaibhavc@10.217.212.97//home/vaibhavc/.bash_profile

Comment: 2 slashes `//` after the `remotehost` is important. Single slash will not work

Comment: If you have a different username on the remote host than your current host, you would use `vimdiff /path/to/file scp://username@remotehost//path/to/file`

Comment: how can you do this with two remote hosts with id_rsa key files @JaredC?

Comment: @Manatax, I'm not sure what you mean? If I have my id_rsa private key on my host, and my public key on the remote host, and locally I'm userA, but remotely I'm userB, then I need to include the username as part of my connection to the remote host. A shorthand way of doing that is like I showed above, prepending the username followed by @ before the host name.  Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning it doesn't work if you need sudo to read the file on the remote host.

Answer (score 187):

You can do it with Bash's [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
 diff foo <(ssh myServer 'cat foo')
```

or the same with

```
 ssh myServer cat foo | diff foo -
```

Or, if both are on remote servers:

```
diff <(ssh myServer1 'cat foo') <(ssh myServer2 'cat foo')
```

Comment: yeah, something like this, but for directories :)

Comment: How do you mean for directories, could always replace cat with ls

Comment: I suspect that 'for directories' means doing a recursive diff

Comment: I found that this technique didn't work for me if my remote host required a password. The password prompt didn't seem to work well with the redirection and couldn't be successfully completed. If you use ssh keys this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This is a great general solution to many problems.  Instead of 'cat foo' you could use 'find /foo/bar -type f | while read file; do echo "**** $file"; cat "$file"; done' and you'd have a list of the file names and file contents to diff.

Comment: @AdamFranco for those who use passwords, MFA, or other login methods that require a prompt, ControlMaster is helpful. It allows multiplexing over a single session. You can log into the host in one terminal window, then ssh in another terminal window can run without having to authenticate. Details here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing

Answer (score 73):

If you just want to see what files are different, rather than a diff of the actual files, then you can use `rsync --dry-run`

Comment: rsync -n is the short version.

Comment: Great - if you need to use another port, use rsync -e "ssh -p 2222" <SRC> <DST>

Comment: This just lists all files unless you use additional flags ( see https://serverfault.com/a/591988/125286 ).

Answer (score 19):

Here's another quick and dirty command line recipe. Unlike the chosen answer, it works inside of makefiles:

```
ssh [login]@[host] "cat [remote file]" | diff - "[local file]"
```

Comment: @Steve Dickinson - what do you mean by "it works inside of makefiles" ?

Comment: This is also a nice solution if you're suffering from vim allergy like myself. :)

I created a bash script that compares the same file on two different hosts, useful when migrating services between machines and comparing config files. See https://gist.github.com/jhqv/dbd59f5838ae8c83f736bfe951bd80ff

Comment: This solution also works if your remote host requires a password.

Answer (score 11):

Use scp to bring the files to a common machine and diff them there?

Or, if you just want to know if the files *are* different or not, hash them with md5sum on each machine.

You could also look into something like [SSHFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS), but I don't know how well an algorithm like diff performs over that.

Comment: An easier way to see if the files are different or not is `rsync --dry-run`.

Comment: I had forgotten about SSHFS. This worked great for me...

Answer (score 10):

One way, if it is possible on your system would be to simply mount the remote filesystem with [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).

Comment: diff is usually one-shot action, like to check config difference. Mounting filesystem each time is possible, but not convinient. I'd better tar and scp.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `rsync` in dry run mode, as suggested briefly in [another answer](https://serverfault.com/a/62366/154390). It lists any files that are different.

For that, use the `rvnc` options (`r`=recursive, `v`=verbose, `n`= dry-run, `c`=checksum). With `rsync` in pull mode (`rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST:SRC... [DEST]`), an example is:

```
rsync -rvnc root@182.18.158.207:/var/www/html/dev/ .
```

*Remember*, this provides no info on whether the local or remote file is newer. Just if they differ.

Comment: I also had to add `i` (itemize-changes) to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

If you have sshfs and need to diff directories:

```
mkdir remote_path
sshfs user@host:/path/ remote_path
diff -r path remote_path
```

Answer (score 2):

- on your local machine, make a recursive copy of the directory you want to diff. For instance:

  ```
  cp -R dir replica
  ```
- use rsync to replicate the remote directory over the local copy:

  ```
   rsync remote:/path/to/dir replica
  ```
- use diff to find difference between the local directory and the local replica of the remote one:

  ```
  diff dir replica
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it.

I used SFTP to the remote server and entered my username/pwd when prompted.
Then I used the dir that was created in the `.gvfs` dir in my home directory in the diff command.

```
diff -r --brief /home/user dir/.gvfs/SFTP\ on\ freenas.local/path to dir/dir1 /path to local dir/dir2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a script that can help to diff local folder and  remote folder.:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 LOCALFOLDER=/var/www/tee
 REMOTEFOLDER=$(ssh root@111.111.111.1 'ls -lA /hfs/tee'| grep -E '^total' | cut -d " " -f 2 > remotessh.txt)
 COMMAND=$(ls -lA $LOCALFOLDER | grep -E '^total' | cut -d " " -f 2 > localssh.txt)
 REM=$(cat remotessh.txt)
 LOCAL=$(cat localssh.txt)

 echo $LOCAL
 echo $REM

 if [ $REM -eq $LOCAL ]
 then
      echo Directories are the same
 else
      echo Directories are differnt
 fi

 #diff localssh.txt remotessh.txt | grep -E '^total' | cut -d " " -f 2
```

Answer (score 1):

http://myfedora.co.za/2012/04/diff-two-remote-file-systems/

```
diff <(/usr/bin/ssh user1@192.168.122.1 'ls /opt/lib/') <(/usr/bin/ssh user2@192.168.122.1 'ls /tmp/') | grep -i ">" | sed 's/> //g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) mounted across ssh.  It won't be all that fast, but you can use your full suite of tools that expect everything to be on a local filesystem.  An alternative is NFS over a tunnel made with "ssh -w" (or other communications where ssh isn't the limitation).

Answer (score 1):

You could also try generalizing the approach by creating a bash function, possibly in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
myrdiff() { ssh root@"$1" cat "$2" | diff -s - "$2" ; }
```

then invoking it with a construct like:

```
myrdiff vm20-x86-64 /etc/gdm/Init/Default
```

By invoking diff with `-s`, this will also report if the files are identical.

Answer (score 0):

using `grep`

```
remote ip: 172.16.98.130
remote file: /etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys
local file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Now compare the contents of remote file with the local file using `grep`

```
grep -w "$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" <<< $(sshpass -p "mypassword" ssh root@172.16.98.130 'cat /etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys')
```

check the success status of the grep command

```
echo $?
# 0
```

Using this idea to setup SSH passwordless login:

```
if ! grep "$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" <<< $(sshpass -p "mypassword" ssh root@172.16.98.130 cat /etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys) &>/dev/null; then
  cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | sshpass -p "mypassword" ssh root@172.16.98.130 "cat >> /etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys"
fi

ssh root@172.16.98.130
```

**Note:**
Make sure `sshpass` package is installed for passing password non-interactively to `ssh` command.

Comment: sshpass leave an unencripted password in your logs. I wouldn't use this in production. Set up SSH keys for logins.

Answer (score 0):

I use  `| cat` at the end of the command for interactive password prompts and `sdiff` because it is easier to read than `diff` :

So between local and remote, type :

```
sdiff -s cat myfile<(ssh server1 'cat myfile') | cat
```

and between two servers, type :

```
sdiff -s <(ssh server1 'cat myfile') <(ssh server2 'cat myfile') | cat
```