# Provide sudo password over ssh while using Bash process substitution?

Tags: ssh, bash

*My question can be seen as an extension of [How do diff over ssh?](https://serverfault.com/q/59140/309742) with a little twist.*

#### Environment

macOS Sierra (10.12.3)
OpenSSH 7.3

#### Example situation

I am trying to print a `diff` between two files, one of them is located on a remote host and requires `sudo` for reading.

If this remote file was readable by my remote user (or if I could execute the command with the sudo flag `NOPASSWD`) I would simply execute:

```
diff LOCALFILE <(ssh host 'cat REMOTEFILE')
```

However I do need to authenticate in order to execute the remote command, which means I have to allocate a pseudo-terminal with `ssh -t`, and the following execution never completes:

```
diff LOCALFILE <(ssh -t host 'sudo cat REMOTEFILE')
```

#### Troubleshooting

`ps` shows me that the `ssh` process is stopped:

```
STAT     TIME   COMMAND
S+    0:00.00   diff LOCALFILE /dev/fd/12
T     0:00.03   ssh -t host sudo cat REMOTEFILE
```

The `ssh` process does not respond to SIGTERM at that point, and the file descriptor above does not exist:

```
❯ ls -l /dev/fd
total 0
crw--w----  1 me     tty     16,   2 Feb 23 17:36 0
crw--w----  1 me     tty     16,   2 Feb 23 17:36 1
crw--w----  1 me     tty     16,   2 Feb 23 17:36 2
dr--r--r--  1 root   wheel         0 Feb 23 09:33 4
```

#### Extra notes

I can observe the exact same behavior any time I use `ssh -t` within a process substitution, regardless of whether a password is needed or not for `sudo` (that said I understand the use of `-t` is questionable if no input is expected on the remote host).

#### Bottom line

I'm using `diff` as an example here, but my question is actually more general: is there any way to use a Bash [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) together with a SSH pseudo-terminal allocation?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/111064/126632

Comment: I don't have `requiretty` set, besides my problem is that I actually want to use a tty in that case.

Comment: Why do you think you want a tty? What would it possibly gain you?

Comment: I need to pass my password as input when I execute `sudo` as explained in my question, changing that behavior is not an option.

Comment: Oh, so that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: That was the whole point of the question :) (cf. title and last line). I do appreciate the response though.

Comment: `That was the whole point of the question` - It is often best to make your question **title** the most specific version of your question.  Something like "Provide sudo password over ssh while using process substitution" instead of the more generic option you used.  Having a specific title and first sentence really is really the best way to get good answers and comments.

Comment: This honestly sounds like a job for `expect`, if it is/can be installed on the server.  You *might* be able to get it to work with expect installed locally.  If you just run `ssh -t host sudo cat REMOTEFILE` alone, do you see the sudo password prompt?

Comment: I don't see any prompt, and I can observe the same behavior regardless of whether the sudo command requires a password input or not (i.e. stopped ssh process, no fs, diff seems to hang). As Michael said it's questionable to request a tty if no input is needed, but I was curious to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force sudo to take the password from STDIN using the `-S` option, per [this superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line#67766). Thus the syntax
`diff LOCALFILE <(ssh host 'echo <password> | sudo -S cat REMOTEFILE')` should do what you need, without the need for a pseudo-terminal.

Comment: That works indeed, thanks! I decided to export my password in the environment and use `diff LOCALFILE <(echo $SUDOPASS | ssh host 'sudo -S cat REMOTEFILE')`.